# Display tiff file inside html page

Tags: html, image, tiff

Is it possible to display a tiff image inside an html page? Inside `embed` tag or `img` tag? 
Is there a better way to display tif image with base64 encryption ?

I saw that it is possible to display a regular image (png, jpeg) this way:

```
<div>
    <p>Taken from wikpedia</p>
    <img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
    9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
</div>
```

How about tiff image with base 64 inside html tags ?

I tried this way :

```
<img alt="" src="data:image/tiff;base64,BASE_64_STRING" alt="base64 image name" width="600" height="400" border="1" />
```

But no result was displayed until now.

Comment: @Diodeus link doesn't help

Comment: A browser can (or, more often, can't) display a TIFF inside a base64 *encoded* (base64 is *not an encryption*) data URI, just as it would with a normal linked one, so I think the duplicate is spot on.